# Angular JS Parameter is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I am having trouble when passing a parameter to a function called addToHistory(param). When I try to write to the console it just says undefined, but when I try to pass a number it gets correctly displayed on the console.

```
  $scope.addToHistory = function(title) 
     {

      console.log(" " + title);  //<-- is undefined

         $scope.tasksHistory.push({
        info: title,
        measured: "measured",
        total: "total",
        done: 0,
        id: 2
         });

     };


 <ion-item ng-repeat="task in tasksCollection" ng-controller="HistoryCtrl" ng-click="addToHistory({{task.info}})" href="#/app/history/{{task.id}}">
            {{task.info}} 
           <!--  <i class="icon ion-plus icon-right" ></i> -->
 </ion-item>
```

Comment: `addToHistory(task.info)`, without curly brackets.

Answer (score 3):

```
ng-click="addToHistory(task.info)"
```

Remove the brackets in the function call